# Doing multiple backspaces in a command

Tags: vimscript

I have a script where the first line works:

```
execute "normal!i\<BS>l"
```

But this line does not:

```
let BS = repeat('\<BS>', NUM_CHARS_TO_DELETE)
execute "normal!i" . BS
```

It seems to just literally insert the `\<BS>\<BS>\<BS>\<BS>` into the text. What's wrong with the second version?

Comment: `:h literal-string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you surround the `\<BS>` in the repeat call with double quotes it should work.

```
let BS = repeat("\<BS>", NUM_CHARS_TO_DELETE)
```

Single quotes are used for ["literal strings"](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-%27), i.e. when you don't want any processing/expansion of the contents.

Double quotes allow for expansion of certain string formats such as the `\<xxx>` form used in mappings and `exe` commands.

Valid expansions are shown here: [`:h expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote). It says "Note that double quotes are used" and lists things like `\t` (tab), `\x###` (hex digit) as well as, at the end of the list, the `\<xxx>` form.

Comment: Note, though, that n*backspace is equivalent to `normal! nx`